# Como fazer dois ScrollView na mesma tela em React Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Eu tenho uma tela com vários quadros de altura fixa, e dentro de cada quadro eu tenho uma quantidade de itens. Eu preciso de um `ScrollView` na tela toda para rolar os quadros, mas também preciso de outro `ScrollView` dentro de cada quadro para rolar os itens daquele quadro.

O problema é que quando eu coloco um `ScrollView` envolvendo a tela toda, o segundo ScrollView` de dentro dos quadros para de funcionar, então não consigo rolar os itens daquele quadro.

Tentei utilizar o `scrollEnabled={false}` para ativar ou desativar o `ScrollView` da tela toda, mas mesmo assim o `ScrollView` de dentro do quadro onde rolo os itens não funciona. O `ScrollView` do quadro só funciona se eu subtituir o `ScrollView` que envolve toda a tela por uma `View` com `flex: 1`, mas dessa forma não irei conseguir rolar a tela para visualizar todos os quadros.

Essa é uma imagem de exemplo, preciso rolar a tela para visualizar do "quadro 1" ao "quadro 3", e também preciso rolar dentro de cada quadro para visualizar do "item 1" ao "item 7".  Como posso solucionar esse problema ou obter essa mesma funcionalidade de outra forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código que tenho no momento:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container} scrollEnabled={false}>
      <View style={styles.quadro}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 1</Text>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 1</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 2</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 3</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 4</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 5</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 6</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 7</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.quadro}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 2</Text>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 1</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 2</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 3</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.quadro}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 3</Text>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 1</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 2</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 3</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 4</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 5</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 6</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item 7</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 20,
  },
  titulo: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  quadro: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height: 300,
    marginTop: 30,
    width: 200,
    borderWidth: 3,
  },
  item: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, vou atribuir o estilo do `container` para uma `View` que vai conter todo o código, para evitar de lançar erro (pelo menos nos meus testes) e vamos ativar o `scrollEnabled`.

Como fica:

```js
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView scrollEnabled>
    // ...
   </ScrollView>
 </View>
)
```

Agora vem o seguinte detalhe, isto que voce tenta fazer é o que chamamos de *Nested ScrollView* (`ScrollView` Aninhada) e neste caso devemos observar o seguinte, por padrão, o aninhamento de `ScrollView`s é ativado automaticamente no `iOS`, mas para tê-lo no `Android`, temos que definir os **props** `nestedScrollEnabled` como `true`.

Como fica:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView scrollEnabled>
        <View style={styles.quadro}>
          <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>
            <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 1</Text>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 1</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 2</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 3</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 4</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 5</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 6</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 7</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.quadro}>
          <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>
            <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 2</Text>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 1</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 2</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 3</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.quadro}>
          <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>
            <Text style={styles.titulo}>QUADRO 3</Text>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 1</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 2</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 3</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 4</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 5</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 6</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item 7</Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 20
  },
  titulo: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  quadro: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height: 300,
    marginTop: 30,
    width: 200,
    borderWidth: 3
  },
  item: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Veja como fica no [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/VE_tb6-md).

<sup>Se possuir o EXPO, escaneie o QRCode com o aplicativo</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou. Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Obrigada!